# parse multiple sql output records(using cursor object) in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

In django, I used connections concept to fetch data. The output have multiple records need to parse through it.

```
cursor = connections['configuration'].cursor()
   cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(integrations.trail_userid),integrations.environment, integrations.endpoint, integrations.connectivity_status, integrations.subscription_status from integrations INNER JOIN list_integration_tools ON integrations.endpoint = list_integration_tools.endpoint WHERE integrations.`trail_username`='ambika02'")
   row = cursor.fetchall()
   print(row)
```

This is my CODE
Result of row is ((30, None, 'snow', 'production', 'dev'), (30, None, 'jira', 'production', 'production'))

I need to parse through row to get all values

row[0] gives me the first record (30, None, 'snow', 'production', 'dev'), But how do I parse through the first record

Answer (score 1):

You can even take out all the attributes name along with its values of the table using this into a list of dictionary, that would also help you in parsing in Django template and also will avoid 2 loops in both views and Template

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
     columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
     return [
            dict(zip(columns, row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]

    cursor = connections['configuration'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT(integrations.trail_userid), integrations.environment, 
                             integrations.endpoint, integrations.connectivity_status, 
                             integrations.subscription_status 
                    FROM integrations INNER JOIN list_integration_tools 
                    ON integrations.endpoint = list_integration_tools.endpoint 
                    WHERE integrations.`trail_username`='ambika02'")

   all_data = dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop and iterate through rows. Each row is tuple so you can access the values by its index.

See below example:

```
for subrow in row:
    subrow[0]
    subrow[1]
    subrow[2]
    subrow[3]
    subrow[4]
```

If you want to access first record then try:

```
row[0][0]
row[0][1]
row[0][2]
row[0][3]
row[0][4]
```